# Is using "Doesn't this also..." correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence correct?

> Doesn’t this also apply to your Enterprise architecture?

It's a question following the statement below:

> There are specific requirements that have to be met when building a house: [a list follows]...

Comment: Yes, this is both grammatical and idiomatic. It you elaborate on why you think it might not be, we can address the actual problem you are actually having.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to ELU.  You have provided some context that makes better sense of the point of your question.  However, there is one key element of context missing.  What exactly is meant by "Enterprise architecture"?  Does this mean architecture in the form of buildings designed by and architecture firm called Enterprise?  Or the architecture of a proposed headquarters for the company called 'Enterprise'?  Or to the way in which Enterprise if organised and managed (often referred to metaphorically as 'architecture')?

Comment: @RegDwigнt: It's more of a feeling of it not being correct. I was thinking it should be something like "Doesn't the same apply to..."

Comment: @Tuffy: It's the latter: "the way in which Enterprise if organised..."

Comment: Taking the question you asked:  whether "Doesn't this also apply to Enterprise architecture?" is correct.  I assume you want to know whether it is grammatically correct English, to which the answer is that it is.  It is a particular kind of question:  one which indicates that the speaker expects the answer must be "yes".  Imagine you see someone who looks somehow familiar.  You go up to them and ask:  "Haven't we met before somewhere?, meaning that I think we have and that you will say "Yes.", or, perhaps "By George, you must be Arthur Digby; what on earth are you doing here?"

Answer (score 0):

Well, now you have explained that ‘structure’ in the sense of ‘organisation’ is meant, the meaning is clear.

The Meriam Webster online dictionary does not give this as one of its meanings, but does extend it to computer systems.  Oxford Dictionaries comes closer.

> 2
>   The complex or carefully designed structure of something.
>   ‘the chemical architecture of the human brain’
>   More example sentences
>           2.1The conceptual structure and logical organization of a computer or computer-based system.

So we are getting warmer.  The Cambridge English Dictionary online goes further and cites company organisation.

> The structure of an organisation which influences the relationship between its parts and employees.

So we are there.  The example cited is:-

> He regards this as an opportunity to deliver a radical new departmental architecture.

So now the meaning is obvious.  One participant in a discussion of the building principals of this company, thinks s/he has seen an analogy the the principles that should apply to the **organisational** architecture of this architectural firm.  Whether this observation is wittily apt or whether it is inept depends on the contents of the list, which you have not cited.  But there is no reason why it couldn’t work.

> Well-established vertical (lifts and stairs / managers and managed) and horizontal (passageways, offices, meeting rooms communication cabling / colleague to colleague and group to group communication). An so forth.

Comment: The sentence's meaning is clear even without knowing what "enterprise architecture" is. But in any case the OP didn't ask about enterprise architecture, the issue is whether the phrasing "Doesn't this also apply to X" is grammatical. Which it is. OP said in a comment they thought it should be "Doesn't the same apply to...", which would also be fine.